# How can I get user ip adress with my apache server behind my home's router?

Tags: php, apache, web, router

I'm hosting a server at home with apache and i'm trying to get my user's ip adress using php but what I get is my router's ip adress. It is possible to get their ip adress by like bypassing my router?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the user's IP address.

If you're testing this from your house's network, you will get your router's IP address, but it doesn't mean its not working for someone outside your network.

You can use a service like [Snapshots](http://www.websnapr.com/) or [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) for testing.

Comment: If you're using NAT and port forwarding this should still get you the user's IP, not the router's.

Comment: Great tested from my friend and showed his ip instead of my router :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way for a router to pass addresses through to NATed devices is by appending the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header to the request before sending it along.